# Getting high ping when MacBook Air is connected to Wi-Fi

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, wifi, dns, ping

I have a 13" MacBook Air with Yosemite 10.10.2 installed:

[image: screen-shot]

As soon as I connect it to my WiFi, I get a very high ping (1600 ms) on both my machines: Windows 7 PC and my MacBook. As a result browsing becomes very difficult. I ping 8.8.8.8!

But if I disconnect my MacBook ping becomes normal (70-80 ms) on Windows PC. I've checked ping by disconnecting my PC, restarted my modem-router, switched off Bluetooth on my Mac.

I've a modem + router D-Link 2750u on the ground floor wired to TP Link 740N on the first floor. I've tried connecting only to 2750u also by switching off 740N. I've been using this setup for last 4-5 months, but the issue has started since couple of weeks back.

What else I've tried:

1. Setting DNS to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4
2. Deleting cache.db file from com.apple.safari
3. Booted in safe mode and restarted back. *In safe boot mode I get the usual ping of 70-80 ms* but after restarting and booting in normal mode the ping returns back to 1600 ms.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Please add some ping (`ping -c 3 ip-address`) results to your question: Mac <-> PC, Mac -> Router1/2, Mac -> 8.8.8.8, PC -> Router1/2, PC -> Router1/2 (without the MBA in the network)

Comment: The ping has returned to normal. I don't know how. But since today morning I'm getting a normal ping.

3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 66.880/67.390/67.850/0.398 ms.

I still don't know the problem.

Comment: I've replaced my TP Link 740N with D-Link AC750 and have been using 5 GHz frequency only for my Macbook and iPad.  I'm attaching (ping -c 3 8.8.8.8) results.  --- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 2198.529/2221.333/2251.944/22.494 ms

Comment: OK I think I've understood the issue. Every time I sync my photos from my iPhone to my macbook using iPhotos, it tries to upload the pics on to my "photo stream". I synced my photos on 30.01.2015 around 6 PM and since then the ping has been high. The moment I disabled the photo stream option ping returned back to normal.  I'm not sure why this is happening (if indeed it was the reason).  How do I make sure?

Comment: You may install a network monitor (e.g. Little Snitch). LS is a packet filter (~firewall) but also contains a network monitor (via the menubar). The filter stops working after 3 hours in the trial version - but you may completely disable the filter and only use the monitor. AFAIR the monitor stops working after 14 days in the trial - but that should be enough to hunt down the problem

Answer (score 1):

I was frustrated with a symptom which was :

1. High and spiking ping between 1ms to 9000ms
2. full bar signal but 50%++ loss ping packet
3. RSSI < -70db with 5-7 m distance from wifi router
4. Conflicting country code
5. Safari loading time takes forever, slow loading website (maybe due to loss packet)

What I have done was :

1. Restarting, reconfigure network setting, reconfigure router, diagnose network, deleting lot of plist ---> the symptom still there.
2. resolving COUNTRY CODE CONFLICT --- I was thinking that those symptom occur because CC conflict, thus I was editing the country code to be X2 by changing airportbrcm4331 (my case MacBook Air 2011) --> success but the ping still high. lot of article discuss how to do it.
3. So I think that there was a something wrong with antenna not the modem because there are no indication of wifi failure. so I did a DIY open MBA, check the modem, and find out that the antenna connector loose and not plugged  properly. plug it... put back things...

and voila everything works like charm. low ping, fast Safari response and works like it suppose to be :D

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  A suggestion to improve your answer would be to condense your description of your problem down to one or two lines (Eg. *I had a similar issue with strong signal, dropped packets, etc) and focus more on what worked rather than what didn't.  It's a *very* long read to find the actual answer in there.

Comment: Thx for feedback

Comment: Better, but the solution to the problem was the *country code conflict* and you direct people away from your answer by saying *lot of articles discuss how to do it.*  What you need to do is follow this simple formula:  1) restate a ***brief*** summary of the problem, 2) state the solution (i.e. fix the country code) 3) summary of steps of how to solve the problem, and 4) link to external site for reference (optional, but highly recommended).

Comment: For reference, have a look at the [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) in the [Help Center](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help) on how to write good answers.

Comment: i  suppose to help ppl with what i did to solve this problem, in my point of view, the problem wasn't software because i already did the software things. so i suggest ppl to do hardware check. 

but anyway, if @Allan disagree with how i should present the post,  i will delete my post. simple and clear

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don’t drop packets then checking if your ping is fast and stable to the WiFi access point is the key test.

If so, you have a routing and downastream network issue. If not, it’s interference or a radio / baseband issue. Pinging google shows that somewhere you have a buffering or throttling if the packet loss is low, not that WiFi is implicated.